# css elements is getting overlapped when i make the screen smaller

Tags: html, css

[image]When i make the screen resize the elements are getting resized.
I tried with position:relative, still it is getting overlapped. Also if i resize it the background image is getting splitted like two. Can someone please help in this, not sure what mistake i have done here.
Posting the html and css code below:

```
<body style="background-image: url(./img/bkgrnd.png);background-size: cover;">
    <h3>welcome user!!</h3>
    <button class="ssystem">System</button>
    <button class="sub">Sub-System</button>
    <button class="subsub">Sub-Sub-System</button>
    <div class="box" id="sys">
        <select>
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
            <option>CCC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box1" id="sub">
        <select>
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
            <option>CCC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="sub1">
        <select>
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
            <option>CCC</option>
        </select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #262626;
}

h3
{
    text-align: right;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    top:40%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box select {
    background: #a9a9a9; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-appearance: border;
    outline: none;
}

.box1 select {
    background: #a9a9a9; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-appearance: border;
    outline: none;
}

.box2 select {
    background: #a9a9a9; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-appearance: border;
    outline: none;
}

.ssystem
{
    position: absolute;
    top:40%;
    left: 41%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #a9a9a9; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-appearance: border;
    outline: none;
}

.sub
{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 41%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #a9a9a9; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-appearance: border;
    outline: none;
}

.subsub
{
    position: absolute;
    top:60%;
    left: 41%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #a9a9a9; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-appearance: border;
    outline: none;
}


#button
{
    background: #a9a9a9;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    height:30px;
    width:84px;
    left:63%;
    top:70%;
    border: none;
    color: arial;
    font-size: 16px;

}
#button:hover
{
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I've added some of your elements in flexbox but I am not sure what your required outcome is, you are welcome to amend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #262626;
position:relative;
max-width: 100vw;
}

h3
{
text-align: right;
color: #C0C0C0;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.box {
position:relative;
/* top: 40%;
left: 60%; */
/* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}

.box1 {
position:relative;
/* top: 50%;
left: 60%; */
/* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}

.box2 {
position:relative;
/* top: 60%;
left: 60%; */
/* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}

.box select {
background: #a9a9a9; 
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 35px;
border: none;
font-size: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-appearance: border;
outline: none;
}

.box1 select {
background: #a9a9a9; 
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 35px;
border: none;
font-size: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-appearance: border;
outline: none;
}

.box2 select {
background: #a9a9a9; 
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 35px;
border: none;
font-size: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-appearance: border;
outline: none;
}

.ssystem
{
position:relative;
/* top:40%; */
/* left: 41%; */
/* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
background: #a9a9a9; 
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 35px;
border: none;
font-size: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-appearance: border;
outline: none;
}

.sub
{
position:relative;
top:50%;
/* left: 41%; */
/* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
background: #a9a9a9; 
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 35px;
border: none;
font-size: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-appearance: border;
outline: none;
}

.subsub
{
position:relative;
top:60%;
/* left: 41%; */
/* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
background: #a9a9a9; 
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
width: 250px;
height: 35px;
border: none;
font-size: 15px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
-webkit-appearance: border;
outline: none;
}

.selections_holder {
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.system-buttons-holder {
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.box-holder {
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.submit_button_holder {
 padding-top: 30px;
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: row;
}

#button
{
background: #a9a9a9;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
height:30px;
width:84px;
/* left:63%;
top:70%; */
border: none;
color: arial;
font-size: 16px;

}
#button:hover
{
background: red;
cursor: pointer;
}
    </style>
</head>

    <body style="background-image: url(./img/bkgrnd.png);background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <h3>welcome user!!</h3>

       <div class="selections_holder">
        <div class="system-buttons-holder">
            <button class="ssystem">System</button>
            <button class="sub">Sub-System</button>
            <button class="subsub">Sub-Sub-System</button>
        </div>

        <div class="box-holder">

        <div class="box" id="sys">
            <select>
                <option>AAA</option>
                <option>BBB</option>
                <option>CCC</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="box1" id="sub">
            <select>
                <option>AAA</option>
                <option>BBB</option>
                <option>CCC</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="box2" id="sub1">
            <select>
                <option>AAA</option>
                <option>BBB</option>
                <option>CCC</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="submit_button_holder">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i try to adjust its still getting overlapped. output should be same as posted without getting overlapped with a inch gap btwn two boxes.

Comment: Please try the amended html

Comment: I have edited my CSS, that is the exact output i want without overlapping when resizing the window. As you said i tried following the below link that doesnt help too.."https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_lastmodified"

Answer (score -1):

You can change your body background image to not repeat as below:

```
<body style="background-image: url(./img/bkgrnd.png);background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue, have attached the image above.